# Spring Security Ajax login succeeds authentication null in following requests

Tags: java, ajax, spring, rest, spring-security

We have a pretty strange issue.  We have a 1 page ajax application (think gmail-like) that uses and ajax authentication.  Under normal circumstances it works great.  However we have notice that you try to login while other requests to the server are still open and running.  The login attempt succeeds but then when you call the server again to fetch something user related, the authentication that objects comes out of the session is null.

Like I said, it always happens when connections are open and running prior to the login attempt.  If the login is the only request happening on the time everything is works as expected.

Here is the spring-security.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd" default-lazy-init="true">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myProject"/> <!-- need this? -->

    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

    <security:http pattern="/css/**" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/js/**" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/tmpl/**" security="none" />

    <security:http pattern="/**" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
        <security:custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="legacyAuthenticationProcessingFilter" /> 
        <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="authenticationProcessingFilter"/>
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler" />
        <security:custom-filter before="LOGOUT_FILTER" ref="legacyLogoutFilter" /> 
        <security:remember-me services-ref="#{applicationProperties['security.rememberMeServices']}" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" erase-credentials="false">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="activeDirectoryAuthenticationProvider" />
        <security:authentication-provider ref="singleLogonAuthenticationProvider" />
        <security:authentication-provider ref="serviceAuthenticationProvider" />
        <security:authentication-provider ref="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <!-- single logon remember me -->
    <bean id="singleLogonRememberMeServices" class="com.myProject.security.singlelogon.SingleLogonRememberMeServices" c:userDetailsService-ref="userDao" c:key="#{applicationProperties['security.rememberMeServices.key']}" p:parameter="rememberMe" />

    <!-- 'regular' remember me -->
    <bean id="rememberMeServices" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices" c:userDetailsService-ref="userDao" c:key="#{applicationProperties['security.rememberMeServices.key']}" p:parameter="rememberMe" />

    <bean id="activeDirectoryAuthenticationProvider" class="com.myProject.security.activedirectory.ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider" />
    <bean id="singleLogonAuthenticationProvider" class="com.myProject.security.singlelogon.SingleLogonAuthenticationProvider" />
    <bean id="serviceAuthenticationProvider" class="com.myProject.security.ServiceAuthenticationProvider" />
    <bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider" p:key="#{applicationProperties['security.rememberMeServices.key']}" />

    <!-- custom authentication processing filter that accepts json credentials -->  
    <bean id="authenticationProcessingFilter" class="com.myProject.security.AuthenticationProcessingFilter">
        <constructor-arg value="/login" />
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="rememberMeServices" ref="#{applicationProperties['security.rememberMeServices']}" />
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler"><bean class="com.myProject.security.AuthenticationSuccessHandler" /></property>
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler"><bean class="com.myProject.security.AuthenticationFailureHandler" /></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- dummy implementation supplied to satisfy spring-security -->   
    <bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="com.myProject.security.AuthenticationEntryPoint" />

    <bean id="logoutSuccessHandler" class="com.myProject.security.LogoutSuccessHandler" />

    <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder" />

    <!-- used by AuthenticationSuccess/FailureHandlers -->
    <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper" />

    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000000"/>
    </bean>



    <bean id="legacyAuthenticationProcessingFilter" class="com.myProject.security.LegacyAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
        <constructor-arg value="/j_security_check" />
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler"><bean class="com.myProject.security.AuthenticationSuccessHandler" /></property>
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler"><bean class="com.myProject.security.AuthenticationFailureHandler" /></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="legacyLogoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
        <constructor-arg ref="logoutSuccessHandler" />
        <constructor-arg><bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" /></constructor-arg>
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/Logout.html"></property>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

**UPDATE**

log is attached below as another answer because its too long to put here. we call sleep in the beginning to mimic the behavior of having another ajax request that is processing. we are able to replicate this login bug every time by having this request prior to login being fired. here's a quick summary of how the app flow is

/sleep/15000

/blank - this is a post request specifically trigger browsers to save their password since its an ajax request

/login - actual login script

/isauthenticated - check if user is actually logged in (application specific)

/account/summary - get a users summary (application specific)

/currentuser - gets the current user (application specific)

/sleep/1500 will then end and the session is cleared.

Comment: What version of Spring Security are you using? I'm wondering if you are running into https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1735 If you haven't already try upgrading to the latest version. If that doesn't help, please enable debug logging and post your logs.

Comment: We are on 3.1.1.RELEASE currently.  Will try and get some logs but it will have to wait until monday

Comment: Before trying to get the logs please ensure you are on the latest release (3.1.4.RELASE). There was another bug that was since fixed that may be related to your issue. If that does not help, provide the logs of when the issue occurs ensuring that the logs have the thread name in them (this will help to determine the cause).

Answer (score 0):

```
[application start]
[myapp] 04 Jun 2013 16:22:51,474 | INFO [main] SpringSecurityCoreVersion.<clinit>(33) | You are running with Spring Security Core 3.1.4.RELEASE
[myapp] 04 Jun 2013 16:22:51,478 | INFO [main] SecurityNamespaceHandler.<init>(59) | Spring Security 'config' module version is 3.1.4.RELEASE


[/sleep/15000] START
[myapp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:00,767 | DEBUG [494291573@qtp-1995218271-0] AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(116) | Checking match of request : '/sleep/15000'; against '/css/**'
[myapp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:00,780 | DEBUG [494291573@qtp-1995218271-0] AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(116) | Checking match of request : '/sleep/15000'; against '/js/**'
[myapp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:00,781 | DEBUG [494291573@qtp-1995218271-0] AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(116) | Checking match of request : '/sleep/15000'; against '/tmpl/**'
[myapp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:00,782 | DEBUG [494291573@qtp-1995218271-0] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /sleep/15000 at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
[myapp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:00,782 | DEBUG [494291573@qtp-1995218271-0] HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.readSecurityContextFromSession(139) | HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
[myapp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:00,783 | DEBUG [494291573@qtp-1995218271-0] HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.loadContext(85) | No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.HashSessionManager$Session:1tqlu01iu4prct7j4tsirpkhx@863190940. A new one will be created.
[myapp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:00,783 | DEBUG [494291573@qtp-1995218271-0] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /sleep/150000 at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
[myapp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:00,783 | DEBUG [494291573@qtp-1995218271-0] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /sleep/15000 at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
[myapp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:00,783 | DEBUG [494291573@qtp-1995218271-0] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /sleep/15000 at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LegacyAuthenticationProcessingFilter'
[myapp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:00,784 | DEBUG [494291573@qtp-1995218271-0] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /sleep/15000 at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AuthenticationProcessingFilter'
[myapp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:00,784 | DEBUG [494291573@qtp-1995218271-0] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /sleep/15000 at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
[myapp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:00,784 | DEBUG [494291573@qtp-1995218271-0] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /sleep/15000 at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
[myapp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:00,785 | DEBUG [494291573@qtp-1995218271-0] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /sleep/15000 at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
[myapp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:00,785 | DEBUG [494291573@qtp-1995218271-0] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /sleep/15000 at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
[myapp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:00,786 | DEBUG [494291573@qtp-1995218271-0] AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(102) | Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@90545b24: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@12afc: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 1tqlu01iu4prct7j4tsirpkhx; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
[myapp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:00,787 | DEBUG [494291573@qtp-1995218271-0] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /sleep/15000 at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
[myapp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:00,787 | DEBUG [494291573@qtp-1995218271-0] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /sleep/15000 at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
[myapp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:00,787 | DEBUG [494291573@qtp-1995218271-0] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /sleep/15000 at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
[myapp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:00,788 | DEBUG [494291573@qtp-1995218271-0] FilterSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(185) | Public object - authentication not attempted
[myapp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:00,788 | DEBUG [494291573@qtp-1995218271-0] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(323) | /sleep/15000 reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain


[/BLANK] START
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:05,937 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(116) | Checking match of request : '/blank'; against '/css/**'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:05,937 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(116) | Checking match of request : '/blank'; against '/js/**'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:05,938 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(116) | Checking match of request : '/blank'; against '/tmpl/**'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:05,938 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /blank at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:05,939 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.readSecurityContextFromSession(139) | HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:05,940 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.loadContext(85) | No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.HashSessionManager$Session:1tqlu01iu4prct7j4tsirpkhx@863190940. A new one will be created.
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:05,941 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /blank at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:05,942 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /blank at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:05,943 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /blank at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LegacyAuthenticationProcessingFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:05,944 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /blank at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AuthenticationProcessingFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:05,945 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /blank at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:05,945 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /blank at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:05,945 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /blank at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:05,946 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /blank at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:05,946 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(102) | Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@90545b24: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@12afc: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 1tqlu01iu4prct7j4tsirpkhx; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:05,947 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /blank at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:05,947 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /blank at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:05,947 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /blank at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:05,948 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(185) | Public object - authentication not attempted
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:05,948 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(323) | /blank reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:06,160 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.saveContext(269) | SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:06,162 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(115) | Chain processed normally
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:06,162 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(97) | SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed

[/LOGIN] START
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:06,195 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(116) | Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/css/**'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:06,196 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(116) | Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/js/**'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:06,197 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(116) | Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/tmpl/**'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:06,198 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /login?_=1370377626193 at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:06,271 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.readSecurityContextFromSession(139) | HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:06,272 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.loadContext(85) | No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.HashSessionManager$Session:1tqlu01iu4prct7j4tsirpkhx@863190940. A new one will be created.
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:06,272 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /login?_=1370377626193 at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:06,272 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /login?_=1370377626193 at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:06,273 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /login?_=1370377626193 at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LegacyAuthenticationProcessingFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:06,273 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /login?_=1370377626193 at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AuthenticationProcessingFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:06,293 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] ProviderManager.authenticate(152) | Authentication attempt using com.myproject.security.activedirectory.ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:06,323 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource.setupEnvironment(76) | Removing pooling flag for user admin@myproject.com
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:06,500 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] ProviderManager.authenticate(152) | Authentication attempt using com.sun.proxy.$Proxy194
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:06,503 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] ProviderManager.authenticate(152) | Authentication attempt using com.sun.proxy.$Proxy194
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,513 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] TokenBasedRememberMeServices.rememberMeRequested(296) | Did not send remember-me cookie (principal did not set parameter 'rememberMe')
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,514 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] TokenBasedRememberMeServices.loginSuccess(254) | Remember-me login not requested.
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,531 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.saveContext(292) | SecurityContext stored to HttpSession: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@509b64dc: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@509b64dc: Principal: User[username=admin,enabled=true,accountExpired=false,credentialsExpired=false,accountLocked=false,Granted Authorities: Role(name=ROLE_ADMIN), Role(name=ROLE_USER)]; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@12afc: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 1tqlu01iu4prct7j4tsirpkhx; Granted Authorities: Role(name=ROLE_ADMIN), Role(name=ROLE_USER)'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,532 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(97) | SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed


[/isauthenticated] START
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,539 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(116) | Checking match of request : '/isauthenticated'; against '/css/**'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,540 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(116) | Checking match of request : '/isauthenticated'; against '/js/**'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,540 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(116) | Checking match of request : '/isauthenticated'; against '/tmpl/**'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,540 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /isAuthenticated?_=1370377631538 at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,541 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.readSecurityContextFromSession(158) | Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@509b64dc: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@509b64dc: Principal: User[username=admin,enabled=true,accountExpired=false,credentialsExpired=false,accountLocked=false,Granted Authorities: Role(name=ROLE_ADMIN), Role(name=ROLE_USER)]; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@12afc: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 1tqlu01iu4prct7j4tsirpkhx; Granted Authorities: Role(name=ROLE_ADMIN), Role(name=ROLE_USER)'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,541 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /isAuthenticated?_=1370377631538 at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,542 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /isAuthenticated?_=1370377631538 at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,542 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /isAuthenticated?_=1370377631538 at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LegacyAuthenticationProcessingFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,542 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /isAuthenticated?_=1370377631538 at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AuthenticationProcessingFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,542 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /isAuthenticated?_=1370377631538 at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,543 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /isAuthenticated?_=1370377631538 at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,543 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /isAuthenticated?_=1370377631538 at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,543 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(142) | SecurityContextHolder not populated with remember-me token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@509b64dc: Principal: User[username=admin,enabled=true,accountExpired=false,credentialsExpired=false,accountLocked=false,Granted Authorities: Role(name=ROLE_ADMIN), Role(name=ROLE_USER)]; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@12afc: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 1tqlu01iu4prct7j4tsirpkhx; Granted Authorities: Role(name=ROLE_ADMIN), Role(name=ROLE_USER)'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,544 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /isAuthenticated?_=1370377631538 at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,544 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(107) | SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@509b64dc: Principal: User[username=admin,enabled=true,accountExpired=false,credentialsExpired=false,accountLocked=false,Granted Authorities: Role(name=ROLE_ADMIN), Role(name=ROLE_USER)]; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@12afc: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 1tqlu01iu4prct7j4tsirpkhx; Granted Authorities: Role(name=ROLE_ADMIN), Role(name=ROLE_USER)'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,545 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /isAuthenticated?_=1370377631538 at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,545 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /isAuthenticated?_=1370377631538 at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,545 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /isAuthenticated?_=1370377631538 at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,546 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(185) | Public object - authentication not attempted
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,546 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(323) | /isAuthenticated?_=1370377631538 reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,573 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(115) | Chain processed normally
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,574 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(97) | SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed

[/account/summary] START
[removing this to save space, its redundant ]

[/currentuser] START
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,949 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(116) | Checking match of request : '/currentuser'; against '/css/**'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,950 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(116) | Checking match of request : '/currentuser'; against '/js/**'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,950 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(116) | Checking match of request : '/currentuser'; against '/tmpl/**'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,950 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /currentUser?_=1370377631948 at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,950 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.readSecurityContextFromSession(158) | Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@509b64dc: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@509b64dc: Principal: User[username=admin,enabled=true,accountExpired=false,credentialsExpired=false,accountLocked=false,Granted Authorities: Role(name=ROLE_ADMIN), Role(name=ROLE_USER)]; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@12afc: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 1tqlu01iu4prct7j4tsirpkhx; Granted Authorities: Role(name=ROLE_ADMIN), Role(name=ROLE_USER)'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,951 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /currentUser?_=1370377631948 at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,951 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /currentUser?_=1370377631948 at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,951 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /currentUser?_=1370377631948 at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LegacyAuthenticationProcessingFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,951 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /currentUser?_=1370377631948 at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AuthenticationProcessingFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,952 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /currentUser?_=1370377631948 at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,952 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /currentUser?_=1370377631948 at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,952 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /currentUser?_=1370377631948 at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,953 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(142) | SecurityContextHolder not populated with remember-me token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@509b64dc: Principal: User[username=admin,enabled=true,accountExpired=false,credentialsExpired=false,accountLocked=false,Granted Authorities: Role(name=ROLE_ADMIN), Role(name=ROLE_USER)]; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@12afc: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 1tqlu01iu4prct7j4tsirpkhx; Granted Authorities: Role(name=ROLE_ADMIN), Role(name=ROLE_USER)'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,953 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /currentUser?_=1370377631948 at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,953 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(107) | SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@509b64dc: Principal: User[username=admin,enabled=true,accountExpired=false,credentialsExpired=false,accountLocked=false,Granted Authorities: Role(name=ROLE_ADMIN), Role(name=ROLE_USER)]; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@12afc: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 1tqlu01iu4prct7j4tsirpkhx; Granted Authorities: Role(name=ROLE_CONFIG_ADMIN_ADMIN), Role(name=ROLE_USER)'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,954 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /currentUser?_=1370377631948 at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,954 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /currentUser?_=1370377631948 at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,954 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(337) | /currentUser?_=1370377631948 at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,954 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(185) | Public object - authentication not attempted
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:11,955 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(323) | /currentUser?_=1370377631948 reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:12,016 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(115) | Chain processed normally
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:12,018 | DEBUG [319749910@qtp-1995218271-4] SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(97) | SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
















[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:15,822 | DEBUG [494291573@qtp-1995218271-0] HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.saveContext(269) | SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:15,823 | DEBUG [494291573@qtp-1995218271-0] HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.saveContext(269) | SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:15,824 | DEBUG [494291573@qtp-1995218271-0] ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(115) | Chain processed normally
[myApp] 04 Jun 2013 16:27:15,825 | DEBUG [494291573@qtp-1995218271-0] SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(97) | SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: Are these logs demonstrating the issue at hand? I ask because the only thread that appears anonymous is a continuation of the thread that started before the login attempt. Your description seems to imply that additional calls the user is treated as anonymous too.

Comment: You will notice that the session is only cleared if the original context was not anonymous https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/context/HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java#L303

Comment: This is our issue.  In the normal flow of our application we can have some long running requests and the user can take actions that will prompt them to log in during the original process.  What happens is the long running request finishes and then blows away the session that has the logged in user.

Comment: The logs do not seem to illustrate that the session was blown away since the only anonymous authentication that occurs after a login was a thread that started prior to login. If this were an issue, you would see a request that starts after the login request completes that claims the request was anonymous. Can you please either explain why you feel the logs demonstrate that the session was blown away or can you please update the logs to demo the issue?

Comment: Also I know the logs state you are using 3.1.4.RELEASE but this is only checking the spring-security-config jar. Please ensure ALL spring security jars are 3.1.4.RELEASE. Also if you have a project that can demo the issue please submit a JIRA to http://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC and attach the project